# It is a python algorithm that changes the background color

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

In this program I want to change the background color. I read an image through Pillow, after turning it into a numpy array. Offering a coordinate the algorithm should check the neighbors from top, bottom, left, right if they have the same color as If one of the neighbors respects the conditions then his coordinates will be placed in a queue. The program does not return errors, but the abs () function returns an incorrect result.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
start_time=time.time()
im=Image.open("Capturecasa.png")
data=np.asarray(im,dtype=np.uint8)
back=np.zeros(4,dtype=np.uint8)
back=data[200][1000].copy()
q=[[200,1000]]
u=10
m=[5,5,5,255]
print(back,"!!!!!")
while q:
    i=q[0][0]
    j=q[0][1]
    k=0
    if abs(data[i+1,j,0]-back[0])<u and abs(data[i+1,j,1]-back[1])<u and abs(data[i+1,j,2]-back[2])<u:
        data[i+1,j]=m
        k+1
        q.append([i+1,j])
    else:
        print(back,"!!!!!")
        print(data[i+1,j],abs(data[i+1,j,0]-back[0]),abs(data[i+1,j,1]-back[1]),abs(data[i+1,j,2]-back[2]))
    if abs(data[i-1,j,0]-back[0])<u and abs(data[i-1,j,1]-back[1])<u and abs(data[i-1,j,2]-back[2])<u:
        k+1
        data[i-1,j]=m
        q.append([i-1,j])
    else:
        print(back,"!!!!!")
        print(data[i-1,j],abs(data[i-1,j,0]-back[0]),abs(data[i-1,j,1]-back[1]),abs(data[i-1,j,2]-back[2]))
    if abs(data[i,j+1,0]-back[0])<u and abs(data[i,j+1,1]-back[1])<u and abs(data[i,j+1,2]-back[2])<u:
        k+1
        data[i,j+1]=m
        q.append([i,j+1])
    else:
        print(back,"!!!!!")
        print(data[i,j+1],abs(data[i,j+1,0]-back[0]),abs(data[i,j+1,1]-back[1]),abs(data[i,j+1,2]-back[2]))
    if abs(data[i,j-1,0]-back[0])<u and abs(data[i,j-1,1]-back[1])<u and abs(data[i,j-1,2]-back[2])<u:
        k+1
        data[i,j-1]=m
        q.append([i,j-1])
    else:
        print(back,"!!!!!")
        print(data[i,j-1],abs(data[i,j-1,0]-back[0]),abs(data[i,j-1,1]-back[1]),abs(data[i,j-1,2]-back[2]))
    del q[0]
    if k==4:
        print("yes")
    #print(i,j,data[i+1,j],data[i-1,j],data[i,j+1],data[i,j-1])
im=Image.fromarray(data,'RGBA')
im.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---"%(time.time()-start_time))
```

I checked what my abs () displays, the function returns erroneous numbers.

```
[204 208 211 255] !!!!!
[163 167 170 255] 215 215 215
[204 208 211 255] !!!!!
[  5   5   5 255] 57 53 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, operating on uint8 restricts the results to uint8 too (so abs is useless since the results will always be 0…255).

```
>>> item1
array([155,  59,  69], dtype=uint8)
>>> back
array([255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> item1 - back  # uint8 255 is like -1 int8
array([156,  60,  70], dtype=uint8)
>>> abs(item1 - back)
array([156,  60,  70], dtype=uint8)
```

I suggest you work with your image pixels as `int16`; also I suggest you calculate the distance of the pixel colors:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(data[i,j,:3] - back[:3])))
```

i.e. search if the color is in a sphere of radius 10 around the back color instead of a cube of side 20.

(There might be a handier function that escapes me now)